# I have a Python code saved in .py but the commands dont happen as they should

Tags: python

```
i = 1

while i <=5:
 print (i)
 i=i + 1 
print ("ok")
```

so this is not exactly my code but of a python tutorial on sololearn

it should output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and then stop

but as i do this i get a loop of 1

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

which i believe is not corect

so where im getting is am i making a mistake while overtyping (wivh i have surely corrected) or is this code a wrong code wich has been wrongly used in the app

OR did the python version change so this doesnt work anymore

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. Copy-and-pasting your code gives the "expected" output. Please provide a *reproducible example* of the bug.

Comment: This should work if the code you mentioned here is exactly the same you are using

Comment: You write "this is not exactly my code but of a python tutorial on sololearn." Please copy-and-paste your exact code into your question.

Comment: I imagine it's really an indentation problem, but your code above as-is is correct: https://repl.it/FF6j/0 (hit the _Run_ button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your indentation. This happens when your `i = i + 1` is not in the loop.

You are running this code, which runs infinitely and prints `1`:

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    print(i)
i=i + 1 
print("ok")
```

but you want this:

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1 
print("ok")
```

---

Also, **always** use four spaces to indent Python code. That way it's much more obvious when the indentation is wrong.

Comment: As per the content mentioned in the question, there is indentation present

Comment: Uh, wouldn't this result in an infinite loop?

Comment: "i get a loop of 1" - the OP has an infinite loop. Also, "this is not exactly my code"

Comment: I interpreted it as 1 printed 5 times... the OP is vague though.

Comment: Just use a good ide (*totally not promoting notepad++*) that shows you either different colors for indentation levels or those that show brackets

Comment: hey i tryd and it worked but i see the same  code so where exactly did i do it wrong?

Comment: Look at the indentation. In python, indentation is what defines blocks.

Comment: Pro-user tip: Sneak onto your co-worker's computer and set his default editor to use a mixture of tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the line that increments `i` is not executing in the loop. There a few possible reasons for this:

- Maybe the line isn't in your source code. Please confirm that the line is present.
- Maybe the line is commented out. The comment character in a Python program is `#`. Ensure that that character does not appear anywhere on the line.
- Maybe, and this seems to me to be the most likely, the line is not indented correctly. In Python, indentation is significant. The body of a loop must be indented further than the `while` line. The first line that is not indented marks the end of the loop. Ensure that your code doesn't look like this:

```
i = 1

while i <=5:
    print (i)
i=i + 1 
print ("ok")
```

- You may be missing tabs and spaces. Please ensure that all of the indentation in your program is exclusively the tab character or exclusively the space character, and never a mix of the two. The consensus in the Python community is to always use spaces, never tabs.